# Python String to list processing

Tags: python, string, file, list

I feel my recently gained knowledge is still not sufficient when it comes to string processing. Please help me solve the below problem statement:
(Please note:This is the simpler version of my requirement)

So.. I have a file (myoption) with content as below:

```
day=monday,tuesday,wednesday
month=jan,feb,march,april
holiday=thanksgiving,chirstmas
```

My python script should be able to read the file and process the read info such that in the end i have three list variables as below:

```
day --> ['monday','tuesday','wednesday']
month --> ['jan','feb','march','april']
holiday --> ['thanksgiving','christmas']
```

Please note:
As per my requirement, the format for contents in myoption file should be simple.
Hence You are free to modify the format of 'myoption' file without changing the content - This is to give you some flexibility.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why not stick with a classic format and just use ConfigParser?

Comment: @Raymond Thanks for informing about configparser, I will look into it.

Comment: @AnimeshSharma I like the confiparser answer, anyway I suggested you how to do it with your format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [the standard `ConfigParser` module](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) your data would need to be in [INI file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), and so would look something like this:

```
[options]
day = monday,tuesday,wednesday
month = jan,feb,march,april
holiday = thanksgiving,christmas
```

And then you could read the file as follows:

```
import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('myoption.ini')
day = parser.get('options','day').split(',')
month = parser.get('options','month').split(',')
holiday = parser.get('options','holiday').split(',')
```

Comment: Is there anyway to **append** new data into the INI file using configparser? Using .set I am able to add data, but it overwrites old file.
Hence If i am appending new data to old INI file - as of now i Have to add new and old data, which requires additional resources.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple answer:

```
s = 'day=monday,tuesday,wednesday'
mylist = {}
key, value = s.split('=')
mylist[key] = value.split(',')

print mylist['day'][0]

Output: monday
```

Comment: Better getting used to not using `list` as a variable name, it hides the builtin and may lead to hard to debug bugs.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that after I posted the answer, re-editing.

Comment: Thanks Alvin for your time. Now i know two solutions to my problem :)

Comment: I'd advocate `ConfigParser` as the first choice (ie: do not reinvent the wheel whenever possible :).

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the [`ConfigParser` module.](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your file in YAML or XML if you want your application respect a standard. 
Anyway, if you want to keep your simple format, this should word:

Given the file **data**:

```
day=monday,tuesday,wednesday
month=jan,feb,march,april
holiday=thanksgiving,chirstmas
```

I propose this **python script**

```
f = open("data")
for line in f:
  content = line.split("=")
  #vars to set the variable name as the string found and 
  #[:-1] to remove the new line character
  vars()[content[0]] = content[1][:-1].split(",")
print day
print month
print holiday
f.close()
```

The output is

```
python main.py 
['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday']
['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april']
['thanksgiving', 'chirstmas']
```